Decimate Collapse has uneven results when used with surrounding Vertex Group
I  am trying to reduce the number of faces in my model to get a low poly look on the top surface only. I tried using the Decimate modifier with a vertex group to only decimate the "inside" vertices and not change the outside border vertices since I have other objects that I want the model to fit into when 3D printed. How can I get Decimate to evenly reduce the faces in the model when a vertex group is specified?
 I cut the model in half for the uploaded file due to size but it has the same behavior.
When I use Decimate with a ratio of 0.0010 on the entire object without vertex group, the top surface has sufficient reduced faces to get the low poly look I want but the vertices of the outside border are also changed.
original object

vertex group of outside border and bottom face

I created a vertex group that includes all the bottom and outside border vertices with the following steps

edit mode for vertex
select a vertex on bottom
select > side of active
set to negative axis, Z axis
select > select more
assign to vertex group

After adding the Decimate modifier with the ratio set to 0.001, I get the following two results with/without the vertex group set in the Decimate modifier:
Decimate without vertex group

Decimate with vertex group

As you can see, the decimate result without vertex group looks a lot better. In fact, using any decimate ratio under 0.5 almost always results in the bad result with the vertex group. I think the vertex group forcing decimate to keep the same number of outer border vertices is making it not evenly decimate the interior vertices since it is trying to link the highest interior vertices to every border vertices.
Is there a way to get the top surface to have an evenly decimated low poly effect while keeping the outside border vertices in place? I could not find a good explanation of vertex weights but think that could help. I'm not set on using Decimate if there are alternatives. Thanks!

I'm able to get a nice low-poly surface with ratio of 0.52. The threshold is quite sensitive yes, but I don't see any issue with it.

I wasn't able to go lower than 0.52 but I found the Merge by Distance tool to do a similar effect. I'm having issue triggering the tool with python so I made a new question for it https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/327190/merge-by-distance-remove-double-removes-0-vertices-when-scripted-with-bpy
